# Better way to ask if user has multiple records in database

Tags: c#, linq

I have this line of code:

```
var userHasMultipleProjects = _context.Clients
    .Where(x => x.IdentityId == user.Id)
    .Select(a => a.Projects)
    .Count() > 1 ? true : false;
```

Can I use `Any()` with some condition where user has more than one project?

Comment: `? true : false` is redundant, and can simply be removed.

Comment: `Skip(1).Any()` instead of `Count() > 1`

Comment: Depending on the ORM, Skip may require a preceding OrderBy.

Answer (score 0):

The below would return true/false if `Projects.Count() > 1`:

```
 _context.Clients
    .Where(x => x.IdentityId == user.Id && x.Projects.Count() > 1)
    .Any();
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to know if there is more than one? How about this

```
bool moreThanOneAvailable = FetchSomeData()
    .Skip(1)
    .Any();
```

Or in your case:

```
bool userHasMultipleProjects = _context.Clients
    .Where(client => client.IdentityId == user.Id)
    .SelectMany(client => client.Projects)
    .Skip(1)
    .Any());
```

In words: from all Clients, keep those Clients that have a value for property IdentityId that equals the primary key that is in user.Id

From each of the remaining Clients (we expect only one Client), get their Projects and make one sequence of all these Projects.

From this sequence or Projects, disregard the first and see if there are Projects left.

If you want all Clients that have more than one Project:

```
var clientsWithMoreThanOneProject = dbContext.Clients
    .Where(client => client.Projects.Skip(1).Any());
```

In words: from all Clients, keep only those Clients, that have Projects left, if you disregard their first Project, or in other words: keep only those Clients that have more than one Project.